# NumberFormat Columns of Datagrid in Flex

Tags: datagrid, flex4

I am filling my datagrid using XML as datasource. I need to format the numeric columns with thousands of separators. Thus I have created a `<mx:NumberFormatter id="setNumberFormat" .../>`

But I fail to use it in the code below. (See the comment //Format Numbers using numberFormatter)

```
for each(var item in fieldsXMLListNew){

                    //Copy all columns in to a proxy 
                    var dgColumns:Array =  myGrid.columns; 
                    //create a new dynamic Column 
                    var aColumn:DataGridColumn =  new DataGridColumn(); 
                    // add parameters 

                    aColumn.dataField = '@' + item.attribute("field"); 
                    if (item.attribute("data_type") == "N"){ //Numeric Fields Only
                        //Sort Numeric Columns
                        aColumn.sortCompareFunction = xmlDataGridNumericSorter(item.attribute("field").toString());
                        //Format Numbers using numberFormatter
                        setNumberFormat.format(item.attribute("field").toString());
                    }
                    aColumn.headerText =  item.attribute("header_text");
                    //add to proxy 
                    dgColumns.push(aColumn); 
                    //copy all  in to Data Grid columns again. 
                    myGrid.columns = dgColumns; 

                }
```

Any tweaking to this code so that it takes the number format?

Comment: You mentioned fail to use. What is the problem? if your item is <node field="123"/> then attribute name is "field" with  value "123". setNumberFormat.format(item.attribute("field").toString()); is same as setNumberFormat.format(123);

Answer (score 0):

Use labelFunction in each column that you want, assinging the labelFunction:

```
<s:GridColumn dataField="field" labelFunction="myLabelFunction"/>
```

The labelFunction:

```
private function myLabelFunction(item:Object, column:GridColumn):String
        {   
            return setNumberFormat.format(item[column.dataField]);
        }
```